# Who was Rambam responding to when he argued for free will against the idea that everything is pre-destined/pre-determined? Did any thinkers believe it

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, rabbis, historical-figures, free-will-bechira

It is well known that Rambam advocated against the ideas that everything is pre-destined and pre-determined and that he believed in (absolute) free will for humanity. The fact that he felt that it was necessary to dedicate a section to writing against this, means that it was not an uncommon belief among some people. Therefore, I wanted to ask whether there were any of his contemporaries (philosophers, thinkers) who subscribed to such a view and who was he writing this towards?

Comment: https://etzion.org.il/en/philosophy/issues-jewish-thought/issues-mussar-and-faith/free-will-2

Comment: @רבותמחשבות  All of the people mentioned in the article, including R. Chasdai Crescas, R. Mordechai Yosef Leiner, R. Yitzchak Luria and R. Zadok HaKohen were long after Rambam though, so it doesn't really answer my question since I'm asking about the contemporaries of Rambam that he was responding to when he was alive.

Comment: @setzu that's true, and why I posted it only as a link. I'm sure that you are correct that there were specific people that felt this way at Rambam's time, but he likely included it because he deals with much Greek philosophy, and according to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinism#History) deterministic views were held by the same Greek philosophers that Rambam often quotes, like Aristotle.

Comment: IIRC, it was a sect of Muslims.